# Unwanted behaviour in phaser weapon plugin

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I am having difficulty in handling collision between asteroid and bullets.
The collision is never happening!!!

```
        <!doctype html> 
        <html lang="en"> 
        <head> 
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <title>My Game</title>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.6.2/phaser.min.js"></script>
            <style type="tex`enter code here`t/css">
                body {
                    margin: 0;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body background-color = "#6666ff">

        <script type="text/javascript">


        var game = new Phaser.Game(1090, 525, Phaser.CANVAS, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update, render: render });

        function preload() {

            game.load.image('neb', 'nebu.jpg');
            game.load.image('ship', 'thrust_ship5.png');
            game.load.spritesheet('bullet', 'rgblaser.png', 4, 4);
            game.load.image('asteroid', 'asteroid1.png');
            game.load.audio('boden', 'war1.mp3');
            game.load.audio('fire', 'fire1.wav');

        }

        var sprite;
        var weapon;
        var cursors;
        var fireButton;
        var fx;
        var asteroid;

        function create() {

            back = game.add.image(-400, -400, 'neb');
            weapon = game.add.weapon(40, 'bullet');
            asteroid = game.add.image(800,200,'asteroid');
            music = game.add.audio('boden');
            music.loop = true;
            fx = game.add.audio('fire',0.1);


            back.smoothed = false;


            music.play();


            weapon.setBulletFrames(0, 80, true);

            weapon.bulletKillType = Phaser.Weapon.KILL_WORLD_BOUNDS;

            weapon.bulletSpeed = 400;

    //  Speed-up the rate of fire, allowing them to shoot 1 bullet every 50ms
            weapon.fireRate = 50;
```

Wrap bullets around the world bounds to the opposite side

```
            weapon.bulletWorldWrap = true;

            sprite = this.add.sprite(400, 300, 'ship');
            game.physics.enable(sprite, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
            game.physics.enable(asteroid, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
            game.physics.enable(weapon, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
            sprite.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
            sprite.anchor.set(0.5);

            game.physics.arcade.enable(sprite);

            sprite.body.drag.set(70);
            sprite.body.maxVelocity.set(200);
```

Tell the Weapon to track the 'player' Sprite
With no offsets from the position
But the 'true' argument tells the weapon to track sprite rotation

```
            weapon.trackSprite(sprite, 0, 0, true);

            cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

            fireButton = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.KeyCode.SPACEBAR);

        }

        function update() {


            game.physics.arcade.collide(asteroid,weapon, collision_handler, null, this);


            if (checkOverlap(asteroid, sprite))
            {
                console.log("Hi, overlap occured!");
                asteroid.kill();
            }


            if (checkOverlap1(weapon, asteroid))
            {
                console.log("Hi, overlap occured in iffffffffffffffff!");
                asteroid.kill();
                //weapon.kill();
            }


    //game.physics.arcade.collide(weapon, asteroid);
    //game.physics.arcade.overlap(weapon, asteroid, collisionHandler, null, this);


            game.physics.arcade.overlap(sprite, asteroid, hitEnemy, null, this);

            if (cursors.up.isDown)
            {
                game.physics.arcade.accelerationFromRotation(sprite.rotation, 300, sprite.body.acceleration);
            }
            else if (cursors.down.isDown)
            {
                game.physics.arcade.accelerationFromRotation(sprite.rotation, -300, sprite.body.acceleration);
            }
            else
            {
                sprite.body.acceleration.set(0);
            }

            if (cursors.left.isDown)
            {
                sprite.body.angularVelocity = -300;
            }
            else if (cursors.right.isDown)
            {
                sprite.body.angularVelocity = 300;
            }
            else
            {
                sprite.body.angularVelocity = 0;
            }

            if (fireButton.isDown)
            {
                weapon.fire();
                fx.play();
            }

            game.world.wrap(sprite, 16);



        }

        function render() {

           // weapon.debug();

        }

        function hitEnemy (one, two) {
                one.kill();
                two.kill();
                console.log("Hit");
         }

         function checkOverlap(spriteA, spriteB) {

            var boundsA = spriteA.getBounds();
            var boundsB = spriteB.getBounds();

            return Phaser.Rectangle.intersects(boundsA, boundsB);

        }


         function checkOverlap1(spriteA, spriteB) {

            var boundsA = spriteA.bounds;
            var xcor = spriteA.x;
            var ycor = spriteB.y;
            var boundsB = spriteB.getBounds();
            //console.log(xcor + "" + ycor);
            //console.log("Inside Collision 1");

            //console.log(Phaser.Rectangle.contains(spriteB,xcor, ycor));
            return Phaser.Rectangle.contains(spriteB,xcor, ycor);

        }

        function collision_handler (object1, object2) {
                 //object1.kill();
                 object2.kill();
        }



        </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```